# Home and Contact Us tab's hover effects in my dropdown navigation menu not how I want it

Tags: html, css

The problem is when I hover over the Home item/tab it changes to a square block and covers the nav bar rounded corners. When I hover over the Contact Us tab/item it changes to a square block and stops short and doesn't go to the end of the nav bar. How can I fix these hovers?

The html of my nav bar:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/">Home</a>
</li>

<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=12">About Us</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=19">Why OSTech</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=21">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=23 ">Case Study 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=25">Case Study 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=27">Green IT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=29">OSdesk Intel vPro</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=31">Workstation Innovation</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=33">Consolidation and Centralisation</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=35">The Green Grid</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=37">Clean Technologies</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=39">OSdesk Remote Management</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/">What We Do</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=41">OSdesk</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=43">OSguard</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=45">OSmon</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=47">OSvault</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=49">OSmail & OShost & OSshare</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=52">OStrack & OSdms</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=54">OSarchive & OSgroup</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=62">OSfaq & OShelp</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=56">OSbill & OScal</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=16">Contact Us</a><ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The css of my nav bar:

```
#nav {

    display: block;

    position:relative;

    border: 1px solid #002799;

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    border-radius: 15px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;

    -moz-border-radius: 15px;

    height: 40px;

    width: 470px;

    margin: 0px auto;

    font: Bold 16px Verdana;


}

#nav ul {

    margin: 0px;

    padding: 0px;

    min-width:250%;


}


#nav li {

    list-style: none;

    float: left;

    position: relative;



    width:auto;
}




#nav ul li {

    list-style: none;

    float: left;

    position: relative;

    width:auto;

}

#nav ul li:last-child a {

    border:none;

}

#nav ul li:hover {

    background: #060652;







}



#nav ul li:hover ul {

    display:block;

    width:100%;
}

#nav ul ul {

    display: none;

    position:absolute;

    left:0px;

    min-width:250%;

    z-index: 999;

    background-color: #4970E3;

}

#nav ul ul li {

    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

    display:block;

    float: none;


    z-index: 999;

    width: auto;

}

#nav ul ul li a {

    border-right: none;

    font: Bold 16px Verdana;

    width: auto;

}

#nav ul li a {

    text-decoration: none;

    display: block;

    border-right: 1px solid #121B3E;

    padding: 10px 15px;

    color: #fbfbfb !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this lines to your `css` :

```
 #nav ul li.right:hover {
   border-radius: 14px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:0;
   border-top-left-radius:0;
   width:137px;
}

#nav ul li.left:hover {

  border-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0;
  border-top-right-radius:0;

}
```

and change the `li` tag contains ***`Home`*** like ***`this`***:

```
<li class="left"><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/">Home</a>
</li>
```

and `li` tag contains ***`Contact Us`*** like ***`this`***:

```
<li class="right"><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=16">Contact Us</a><ul>
```

[This is Demo](http://jsbin.com/zuqumaja/7/edit)

Comment: This worked! Works exactly like in your demo. Thanks Kiyarash.

Comment: Okay I will do that.There is one slight imperfection I noticed with it in internet explorer. The contact Us tab just has a bit of white in between the right border and the block when in normal state. You can have a look at the web site now http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/ if you want. What should I change to fix this?

Comment: what's your I.E version?

Comment: I managed to fix this just by changing the border radius and width by a little. So all is good now. My I.E version is 11.0.

Comment: OK... I'm glad the answer helped... be Happy :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I added a div border gradient with Contact Us text inside in the sidebar of my site. I have the same problem. There is white space at the bottom and right between the border and the gradient. I tried changing the border radius but nothing seems to be happening. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: would you make a fiddle? or update my `demo` in my answer and share new link...?

Comment: Okay I will create a fiddle and let you know when it is done. Also there is a slight imperfection in the nave bar in your demo. In every browser except chrome when you hover over contact us the tab's width stretches a bit. Doesn't do that in Chrome though.

Comment: I have created the fiddle. This is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/k8u5X/. The white spaces aren't there in the fiddle and I don't know why. The code is exactly the same. There is also an underline on the contact us text which doesn't appear on my website. Take a look for yourself: http://osweb01.ostech.com.au.

Comment: Use this link instead I have created an account on jsfiddle.net. http://jsfiddle.net/D0rZa/63mrE/

Comment: Okay. The contact us tab navigation part is. I ask a new question for the contact us sidebar.

Comment: Not so much in I.E. When you hover over the contact us tab it is okay but in its normal state I can see a bit of white in between the rounded border and the gradient of the contact us tab. I have created the new question for that sidebar contact us div.

Comment: border-radius is not supported in `I.E 9-`, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp 
Link your new question please...

Comment: New question link is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050889/does-anyone-know-why-does-my-contact-us-sidebar-div-link-has-white-space-between

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=12">About Us</a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=19">Why OSTech</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=21">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=23 ">Case Study 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=25">Case Study 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=27">Green IT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=29">OSdesk Intel vPro</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=31">Workstation Innovation</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=33">Consolidation and Centralisation</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=35">The Green Grid</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=37">Clean Technologies</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=39">OSdesk Remote Management</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/">What We Do</a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=41">OSdesk</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=43">OSguard</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=45">OSmon</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=47">OSvault</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=49">OSmail & OShost & OSshare</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=52">OStrack & OSdms</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=54">OSarchive & OSgroup</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=62">OSfaq & OShelp</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=56">OSbill & OScal</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=16">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

added what you need with

```
#nav ul li.round1:hover {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
#nav ul li.round:hover {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ey9TK/)

Comment: Looks perfect except on I.E 11. The problem with I.E is that some pages move either right or left a bit depending on what page I go to from the nav bar. This is a I.E browser issue with centered websites. Everything on the website except borders or rounded borders moves either right or left a inch on page change.

Comment: So basically what happens with the nav bar is sometimes it moves right with the rest of the page but the outside border stays in the same position causing the white area/gap I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken what Gadgetster did and improved it: http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/ey9TK/3/

You'll notice now that all buttons are curvy and no spaceing!

**CSS:**

```
    body { overflow-y: scroll; }
    .wrapper { width: 100%; text-align: center; }

    #nav {
        display: inline-block;
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid #002799;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
        background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        font: Bold 16px Verdana;
    }

    #nav ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    #nav li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width:auto;
    }




    #nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width:auto;
    }

    #nav ul li:last-child a {
        border:none;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover {
        background: #060652;
    }
    #nav ul li.round1:hover {
        border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
    #nav ul li.round:hover {
        border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover ul {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        margin: 3px 0 0;
        left: 0px;
        min-width: 250%;
        z-index: 999;
        background-color: #4970E3;
    }

    #nav ul ul li {
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        display:block;
        float: none;
        z-index: 999;
        width: auto;
    }

    #nav ul ul li a {
        border-right: none;
        font: Bold 16px Verdana;
        width: auto;
    }

    #nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        border-right: 1px solid #121B3E;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        color: #fbfbfb !important;
    }
```