# Does anyone know why does my Contact Us sidebar div link has white space between rounded border and gradient?

Tags: html, css

I have a contact us gradient div link on my sidebar with a rounded border. The rounded border isn't right on the edge of the gradient div all the way around. The result is there is white space in between the gradient and the border at the bottom and right side. How do I fix this?

I created a fiddle but it is slightly different in the fiddle. There is no white spaces and the div text has an underline. Check it out for yourself.

The fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/D0rZa/63mrE/

```
<div id="sidebar">
<p>Any Questions?</p>
<div class="sidebar-butt"><a href="http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/?page_id=16">Contact Us</a></div>
</div>

#sidebar {

    float: right;

    width: 238px;

    color: #000000;

    padding-right: 5px;

    padding-left: 5px;

    height: 250px;

    border: 1px solid #28A9D6;

    border-radius: 8px;

    margin-top: 4px;

    margin-right: 5px;


}
.sidebar-butt {

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0.27, #496FE3),
    color-stop(1, #121B3E));

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #496FE3 27%, #121B3E 100%);

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #496FE3 27%, #121B3E 100%);

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #496FE3 27%, #121B3E 100%);

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #496FE3 27%, #121B3E 100%);

    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #496FE3 27%, #121B3E 100%);

    width:110px;

    height:28px;

    color:#fbfbfb !important; 

    border-radius:25px; 

    -webkit-border-radius:25px; 

    -moz-border-radius:25px; 

    border: 1px solid #002799; 

    font: Bold 16px Verdana;

    padding: 5px 10px;

    text-align: center;







}

.sidebar-butt:hover {

    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0%    transparent;

    width:110px;

    height:28px;

    color:#fbfbfb; 

    border-radius:25px; 

    -webkit-border-radius:25px; 

    -moz-border-radius:25px; 

    border: 1px solid #002799; 

    font: Bold 16px Verdana;

    background: #060652;

}

.sidebar-butt a {

    color: #fbfbfb;

}
```

My website:
http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/

Comment: I don't see any white space. To remove the underline you can use `text-decoration:none` - http://jsfiddle.net/63mrE/1/

Comment: i not understand your problems.. everything look ok

Comment: Have you looked at my website in I.E 11. There is just a touch of white on the right side of the gradient. There is no white space at the bottom but there is sort of like a thin faint white border above the dark blue border at the bottom.

Comment: In the fiddle it look perfect there are no problems except the text underline which I can fix.

Comment: Take a look at this new fiddle I did: http://jsfiddle.net/AFgWY/ It is the same contact us sidebar with just a few more divs added to it from the webpage it came from. They are wrap, main and content. The contact us sidebar div has white space in between the border on the right side. It has to be something with one of these other divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar li {

    list-style-type: none;

    padding:0px;

    /* float:left; remove this */  

    background-image: url(images/narrow.gif);

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: 8px 15px;

    /* border: 1px solid #AACCEE;  remove this */

    background-color: #FFF;

    width: 230px;

    margin-bottom: 20px;

}
```

Comment: hi.. can you give picture to expected result because i cannot understsand your question clearly.. thanks

Comment: how do I do that in stack overflow?

Comment: I know what the problem is but I don't know what to do. On the Contact Us page, Home page and What We Do page on IE 11 everything move to the left a little except the border around that contact us div gradient on the sidebar. This explains why there is a touch of white on right side inside of the border and gradient.

Comment: If you look at the website again http://osweb01.ostech.com.au on IE 11 look through every page. The contact us sidebar div gradient should look perfect on the about us page and all of the subpages but not on the other pages. If you still can't see what I mean then I will upload some pictures once you tell me how.